# Incompatible operand types int and CellType

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So I am trying to read an excel sheet using Java code. Below is the code:

```
package com.SfHawk.Utility;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
 
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ExcelApiTest {
    
    
        public FileInputStream fis = null;
        public XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        public XSSFSheet sheet = null;
        public XSSFRow row = null;
        public XSSFCell cell = null;
     
        public ExcelApiTest(String xlFilePath) throws Exception
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(xlFilePath);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            fis.close();
        }
     
        public String getCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum)
        {
            try
            {
                int col_Num = -1;
                sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
                row = sheet.getRow(0);
                for(int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++)
                {
                    if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim()))
                        col_Num = i;
                }
     
                row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
                cell = row.getCell(col_Num);
                
     
                if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING)
                    return cell.getStringCellValue();
                else if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC || cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA)
                {
                    String cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
                    {
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
                        Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                        cellValue = df.format(date);
                    }
                    return cellValue;
                }else if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK)
                    return "";
                else
                    return String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "row "+rowNum+" or column "+colNum +" does not exist  in Excel";
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code is giving me an error saying:
**Incompatible operand types int and CellType**

Initially I used cell.getCellTypeEnum() method instead of cell.getCellType(). But cell.getCellTypeEnum() gave me error saying, **The method getCellTypeEnum() is undefined for the type XSSFCell**

How can i fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? And do not have different versions of `apache poi` `jar`s in class path. For example do not have `poi-3.17.jar` and `poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar` and `poi-4.1.2.jar` and `poi-ooxml-3.17.jar` in class path the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Below are the dependencies I have in my pom.xml.       <dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi</artifactId>

<version>3.12</version>

</dependency>





<dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>

<version>3.9</version>

</dependency>

Comment: As said, do not mix different `apache poi` versions. You are mixing `3.12` and `3.9`. But both are ancient and outdated. Do using **one** current version.